# How to Display Live Camera Feed in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avplayer

Is there a way to stream a live video feed from the phone camera directly to AVPlayer? It only seems to accept NSURL arguments. How do I access the camera feed and pipe it into the video player?

Here's an example:

```
NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"congo" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath];
_player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
```

This is close but I don't want to play a movie file.

Comment: Why do you want to use `AVPlayer` to show a live camera feed?

Comment: I'm using the GoogleVR sample code. What should I use instead?

Comment: I can't speak to the GoogleVR sample code but normally you would use `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and `AVCaptureSession` to show a live camera feed.

Comment: Okay great! I've got a live camera feed to the view. Is there a way to display two instances of the same camera?